# Excel VBA - dynamic destination

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic

**I have Acct, #, name in columns A:C**

```
acct    #   name
1585    1   name_1
1585    2   name_2
1585    3   name_3
1585    4   name_4
1585    5   name_5
1586    6   name_6
1586    7   name_7
1586    8   name_8
1586    9   name_9
1586    10  name_10
1587    11  name_11
....
```

The macro groups # and name by acct using a chr(10) return.

The code starts defines the destination for the grouping as follows:

- E2 = account
- F2 = grouping of all #s and names by account

I would like the destination row to Offset to the next row below when acct changes.


For example:

when acct = 1586 the destination should switch to E3 and F3,

when acct = 1587 the destination should switch to E4 and F4, and so on

How do I build that dynamic offset into my code below? Is there a find next empty row function

Can I make any adjustments to my current code to make it more efficient?

This is my first attempt at coding, working with VBA and StackOverFlow.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Sub GroupChrRtn()
Range("A2").Select

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
If Selection.Value = Selection.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
        Range("E2").Value = Selection.Value
        If Range("F2").Value = "" Then
            Range("F2").Value = _
                Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value & " " & Selection.Offset(0, 2).Value
        Else
           Range("F2").Value = Range("F2").Value & Chr(10) & _
                Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value & " " & Selection.Offset(0, 2).Value
        End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Else
    Range("F2").Value = Range("F2").Value & Chr(10) & _
                Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value & " " & Selection.Offset(0, 2).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CRondao suggestion was helpful.

Here's the final code I used referencing a range for matching values:

```
Sub GroupChrRtn()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Sizes As Range

LastSize = ActiveSheet.Range("N65536").End(xlUp).Row
Set Sizes = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(LastSize, 14))

 r = 1

For Each c In Sizes.Cells

 Do While Cells(r, 1) = c.Value
    If c.Offset(0, 4).Value = "" Then
        c.Offset(0, 4).Value = _
        Cells(r, 1).Offset(0, 3).Value & " " & Cells(r, 1).Offset(0, 4).Value
     Else
        c.Offset(0, 4).Value = c.Offset(0, 4).Value & Chr(10) & _
        Cells(r, 1).Offset(0, 3).Value & " " & Cells(r, 1).Offset(0, 4).Value
     End If
 r = r + 1
 Loop
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget about select it is very inefficient.

```
r=2
DO while not isempty(cells(r,1))
 if cells(r,1)=cells(r+1,1) then
   ' do your stuff

 else
  ' do your other stuff
 end if
 r=r+1
LOOP
```

Comment: I got it to work @CRondao! Thank you for your guidance. It got me thinking in the right direction. the Cells command is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

My take, using an insane amount of `Offset`. Disclaimer, of course, that the YMMV because this is purely an alternative to a multitude of other approaches.

**Code:**

```
Sub Group()

    Dim RngAcct As Range, RngNum As Range, RngName As Range
    Dim RngResAcct As Range, RngResNumName As Range
    Dim StrResOne As String, StrResTwo As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set RngAcct = .Range("A2")
        Set RngNum = RngAcct.Offset(0, 1)
        Set RngName = RngNum.Offset(0, 1)
        Set RngResAcct = .Range("E2")
        Set RngResNumName = .Range("F2")
    End With

    StrResTwo = ""
    Do Until IsEmpty(RngAcct)
        StrResOne = RngAcct.Value
        If RngAcct.Offset(1, 0).Value = StrResOne Then
            StrResTwo = StrResTwo & RngNum.Value & " " & RngName.Value & Chr(10)
            RngResAcct.Value = StrResOne
            RngResNumName.Value = StrResTwo
        Else
            StrResTwo = StrResTwo & RngNum.Value & " " & RngName.Value
            RngResAcct.Value = StrResOne
            RngResNumName.Value = StrResTwo
            Set RngResAcct = RngResAcct.Offset(1, 0)
            Set RngResNumName = RngResNumName.Offset(1, 0)
            StrResTwo = ""
        End If
        Set RngAcct = RngAcct.Offset(1, 0)
        Set RngNum = RngAcct.Offset(0, 1)
        Set RngName = RngNum.Offset(0, 1)
    Loop

End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Enjoy!